# Pgfplotstable: display numbers exact as written in file

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

My file is

```
U(V)    I(A)    I/U
0.00    0.000   0 
0.31    0.020   0.065 
1.15    0.075   0.065 
1.82    0.120   0.0659
2.73    0.178   0.0652
3.42    0.224   0.0655
5.08    0.333   0.0656
6.24    0.408   0.0654
7.46    0.488   0.0654
```

And I want to use pgfplotstable to display this data. The problem is, whaterver I try, pgfplotstable rounds the numbers, adds zero's, uses scientific notation etc...

[image]
I tried to add `string type, column type = {r}` to the columns, but now I can't center around the decimal points.

[image]

I want pgfplotstable to display the numbers as I wrote them. I don't want extra zero's, or rounded numbers, fixed numbers, etc...

MWW: see the answer of Torbjørn T.

Comment: Please add a fully compilable code. This usually helps to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dec sep align,precision=4`, and adding specific styles for the first two columns may be what you're after.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
U(V)    I(A)    I/U
0.00    0.000   0 
0.31    0.020   0.065 
1.15    0.075   0.065 
1.82    0.120   0.0659
2.73    0.178   0.0652
3.42    0.224   0.0655
5.08    0.333   0.0656
6.24    0.408   0.0654
7.46    0.488   0.0654
}\data
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   dec sep align,
   precision=4,
   columns/U(V)/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=2},
   columns/I(A)/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=3},
   fixed,
   every head row/.style={
      before row=\toprule,
      after row=\midrule},
   every last row/.style={
      after row=\bottomrule}
   ]{\data}

\end{document}
```

## Single cell formatting

You can also add styles to specific cells, so if there is a value ending with zero in the last column, and you want this included, but you don't want zeros added to other values in that column that is possible, with the `every row <row index> column <column index>` styles. Note that the indices start counting at zero.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
U(V)    I(A)    I/U
0.00    0.000   0 
0.31    0.020   0.065 
1.15    0.075   0.0650
1.82    0.120   0.0659
2.73    0.178   0.0652
3.42    0.224   0.0655
5.08    0.333   0.0656
6.24    0.408   0.0654
7.46    0.488   0.0654
}\data
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   dec sep align,
   precision=4,
   columns/U(V)/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=2},
   columns/I(A)/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=3},
   every row 2 column 2/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=4},
   fixed,
   every head row/.style={
      before row=\toprule,
      after row=\midrule},
   every last row/.style={
      after row=\bottomrule}
   ]{\data}

\end{document}
```

## ... on the other hand

For this case, you could also ditch all the number formatting stuff, and say quite simply `string type,column type={l}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
U(V)    I(A)    I/U
0.00    0.000   0 
0.31    0.020   0.065 
1.15    0.075   0.0650
1.82    0.120   0.0659
2.73    0.178   0.0652
3.42    0.224   0.0655
5.08    0.333   0.0656
6.24    0.408   0.0654
7.46    0.488   0.0654
}\data
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   string type,column type={l},
   every head row/.style={
      before row=\toprule,
      after row=\midrule},
   every last row/.style={
      after row=\bottomrule}
   ]{\data}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's already very nice! One small thing: the last 0 of 0.120 is not displayed. It's measured data and those zeros should really be displayed, they show the precision. Do hou know how I could do that?

Comment: @user238282 Ah, you're right, didn't notice that. Will have a look, and edit if  I find a solution.

Comment: @user238282 Was that better?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great. (The only problem is that if there is a number that ends with a 0 in the third column, that zero is going to be removed, but that's not a problem in this case. If you would find a solution that didn't do this, that would be even more awesome)

Comment: @user238282 New update, two new sections.